# base64 encoding unicode strings in python 2.7

Tags: python, character-encoding, base64, unicode-string, python-unicode

I have a unicode string retrieved from a webservice using the [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org), **which contains the bytes of a binary document** (PCL, as it happens). One of these bytes has the value 248, and attempting to base64 encode it leads to the following error:

```
In [68]: base64.b64encode(response_dict['content']+'\n')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\...\<ipython-input-68-8c1f1913eb52> in <module>()
----> 1 base64.b64encode(response_dict['content']+'\n')

C:\Python27\Lib\base64.pyc in b64encode(s, altchars)
     51     """
     52     # Strip off the trailing newline
---> 53     encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
     54     if altchars is not None:
     55         return _translate(encoded, {'+': altchars[0], '/': altchars[1]})

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 272: ordinal not in range(128)

In [69]: response_dict['content'].encode('base64')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\...\<ipython-input-69-7fd349f35f04> in <module>()
----> 1 response_dict['content'].encode('base64')

C:\...\base64_codec.pyc in base64_encode(input, errors)
     22     """
     23     assert errors == 'strict'
---> 24     output = base64.encodestring(input)
     25     return (output, len(input))
     26

C:\Python27\Lib\base64.pyc in encodestring(s)
    313     for i in range(0, len(s), MAXBINSIZE):
    314         chunk = s[i : i + MAXBINSIZE]
--> 315         pieces.append(binascii.b2a_base64(chunk))
    316     return "".join(pieces)
    317

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I find this slightly surprising, because 248 is within the range of an unsigned byte (and can be held in a byte string), but my real question is: **what is the best or right way to encode this string?**

My current work-around is this:

```
In [74]: byte_string = ''.join(map(compose(chr, ord), response_dict['content']))

In [75]: byte_string[272]
Out[75]: '\xf8'
```

**This appears to work correctly, and the resulting `byte_string` is capable of being base64 encoded, but it seems like there should be a better way. Is there?**

Comment: 248 may be within the range of an unsigned byte, but it's not in the range of standardized ASCII [0-127].

Comment: @Cameron: A true and good point, but it still doesn't explain the problem, as the exact same value, when held in a byte string does not result in that error.

Comment: See my answer :-) What you've done is take the codepoints of the `unicode` string and treat them as bytes. This is... fishy at best, since you're there's no guarantee the codepoints are even within the range 0-255. What's even worse is that nobody else will know how to interpret the byte string later on, since it's in a custom, undefined encoding.

Comment: @Cameron: to reiterate: these data are not character code points, they are binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with binary data, I'm not sure that it's a good idea to use the utf-8 encoding. I guess it depends on how you intend to use the base64 encoded representation. I think it would probably be better if you can retrieve the data as a bytes string and not a unicode string. I have never used the requests library, but browsing the documentation suggests that it is possible. There are sections talking about "Binary Response Content" and "Raw Response Content".

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that encoding as latin-1 yields the exact same sequence of bytes as my workaround.

Comment: @Marcin: You need to make sure that the requests module hasn't assumed that you are working with text, applied a default encoding, and decoded your binary data to unicode. If that is the case you've got trouble. Can you verify that the content is what you expect?

Comment: Having paid a little bit more attention to the docs, it turns out that requests also tells me the encoding that is used to decode the response to unicode, so I can reliably always re-encode with that (and that once again yields the same bytes).

Answer (score 18):

You have a `unicode` string which you want to base64 encode. The problem is that `b64encode()` only works on *bytes*, not *characters*. So, you need to transform your `unicode` string (which is a sequence of abstract Unicode codepoints) into a byte string.

The mapping of abstract Unicode strings into a concrete series of bytes is called *encoding*. Python supports several encodings; I suggest the widely-used UTF-8 encoding:

```
byte_string = response_dict['content'].encode('utf-8')
```

Note that whoever is decoding the bytes will also need to know which encoding was used to get back a `unicode` string via the complementary `decode()` function:

```
# Decode
decoded = byte_string.decode('utf-8')
```

A good starting point for learning more about Unicode and encodings is the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html), and [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: To be clear: the contents of my unicode string are binary data. I cannot change them to some different bytes. Is there an identity encoding?

Comment: @Marcin: You cannot have a `unicode` string containing binary data. That's a contradiction in terms! If the `unicode` string's bytes are supposed to represent binary data (as seems to be the case here), then it shouldn't be stored in a `unicode` object as it's not really Unicode at all!

Comment: Why don't add BOM? Actually this feature helps detecting if a string is UTF-8 or not.

Comment: @sebix: I think it's best if BOMs are usually only used at the start of files; the overhead and complexity of having to check strings everywhere for a BOM seems too high. I got the encoding mixed up, though, the `-sig` one *does* add the BOM.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest first encoding it to something like UTF-8 before base64 encoding:

```
In [12]: my_unicode = u'\xf8'

In [13]: my_utf8 = my_unicode.encode('utf-8')

In [15]: base64.b64encode(my_utf8)
Out[15]: 'w7g='
```

Comment: *encoding to UTF-8* does not make sense. either you encode from UTF-8 to bytes/ascii or you decode from ascii to UTF-8. it's the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to get the response as binary bytes and skip the decoding and encoding steps entirely. There's always a possibility that `requests` will choose an encoding that loses some data or errors out in the round trip.

This part of the docs called ["Binary Response Content"](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) seems to fit your problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's binary data...why encode/decode at all? Specially the "base64.encodestring" part. Below is how I encode images into base64 for adding directly into my python code instead of having extra files. 2.7.2 btw

```
import base64
iconfile = open("blah.icon","rb")
icondata = iconfile.read()
icondata = base64.b64encode(icondata)
```